Google Chrome URLAllowList formatting for javascript
We have a requirement to use URLBlockList in Chrome to deny all javascript execution based on this rule.
We need to use the URLAllowList as mentioned here to permit by exception but cannot seem to get the formatting correct.
The site we're trying to allow is documented here.
and the the javascript is:
javascript:void((function(){andiScript=document.createElement('script');andiScript.setAttribute('src','https://www.ssa.gov/accessibility/andi/andi.js');document.body.appendChild(andiScript)})());

When you look at chrome://policy and see URLBLockList set to javascript://* then you will notice it no longer lets you execute ANDI as a bookmark. We want this to work for this site's .js only and nothing else.
